# How is pointer arithmetic on multidimensional array done below?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

here e is supposed to be the address at a[1] and a is address at a[0].then on subtracting it would be 1 but the result is total bytes between those. is not pointer arithmetic applied here.(ignore warns).

```
int a[10][20][30] = {0};
int *d = a;
int *e = a+1;
printf("%ld", e-d);//why is this not 1
```

Comment: It's not 1 because the types of `d` and `e` are incorrect. And your compiler should be generating warnings to that effect.

Comment: *"(ignore warns)"*. You should almost never ignore warnings.

Comment: If we skip this `*d`/`*e`type mess and instead do `printf("%ld", (a+1) - a);`, I actually get `1`.

Comment: @Jarod42 If by "almost never" you mean "while developing something", then you are right, you can ignore warnings. But if you are compiling something that will actually be used by someone who isn't you, it's almost mandatory that you compile with `-Werror`. Ignoring warnings is never a good idea, in fact, I don't even know why everything besides "hey, look, you have unused function declaration that doesn't have it's definition anywhere, don't forget to do it later okay?"... Wrong pointer types should be errors, C compiler shouldn't hold your hand, but if behaviour will be undefined, it's error.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using incorrect pointer types. In fact compiler even tells you this:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:5:11: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  int *d = a;
```

If we force our way past the errors with casts, the compiler will use these wrong types for calcation:

```
int a[10][20][30] = {0};
int *d = (int*)a;
int *e = (int*)(a+1);
printf("%ld", (long)(e-d));
```

Remember that when substracting pointers the internal formula used by the compiler is `(address2 - address1) / sizeof(type)`. If `sizeof(int) == 4`, and `a` is located at address 1000, this is `(3400 - 1000) / 4 == 600`.

Using the correct type (`sizeof(int[20][30]) == 2400`) gives us the answer of `(3400 - 1000) / 2400 == 1`:

```
int a[10][20][30] = {0};
int (*d)[20][30] = a;
int (*e)[20][30] = a+1;
printf("%ld", (long)(e-d));
```

Comment: how does type in sizeof(type) takes 4 as a[0] and a[1] both type are 600.

Comment: @xehob Because type of `d` and `e` is `int*`, the `int` is used. Compiler doesn't consider the type of `a` because it's not used in the substration expression.

Comment: You could also use `printf("%td", e-d);` since `e-d` has type `ptrdiff_t`.